# After sum in mysql, if the username in the rank list, how to let them get prices?

Tags: php, mysql

now i do an php game assignment related to rank list. My table as below:

Table name `t1`

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| ID | uid   | username  |hpdeduct     | createtime  |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1  | 10    | admin     |50           | 1234567     |
| 2  | 10    | admin     |12           | 1234568     |
| 3  | 10    | admin     |60           | 1234569     |
| 4  | 11    | testing1  |50           | 1234560     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I use the code as below to show the rank list who deduct the boss hp is higher.

```
DB::fetch_all("SELECT sum(hpdeduct) AS totalhitdd FROM t1 GROUP BY uid ORDER BY totalhitdd DESC LIMIT 10";
$kk = 1;
foreach ($ranklist as $l => $m) {
   $m['x'] = $kk++;
   $ranklista[] = $m;
}
```

So I `loop` the the `$ranklista[]` result like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| $m['x']   | $m['uid']   | $m['username']   | $m['totalhitdd']  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 1         | 10          | admin            | 122               |
| 2         | 11          | testing1         | 50                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So now, I would like to let my player get the price when he `uid` or `username` is in this `$ranklista[]`, if he `uid`'s `$m['x']` is 1, can get the first price, if he `uid`s `$m['x']` is 2, can get the second price. I have no idea how to do let script know is it the user can get which one price.

For DB security issue, my DB function was not allowed 2 `SELECT * bla bla` in one `query`.

Thank you.